# Silverlight 4 - Loading a new webpage on button click?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, web-applications, silverlight-4.0

In the older Silverlights, to open up a new webpage I'd use HtmlPage.Navigate, but that doesn't appear to work in Silverlight 4. (Yes, I've loaded `System.Windows.Browser;` )

Thanks in advance!

-Sootah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From MSDN, might using `HtmlPage.Window.Navigate`work?

```
System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(
    new Uri("http://silverlight.net"), 
    "_blank", "height=300,width=600,top=100,left=100");
```

[link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189809%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: I get the error The DOM/scripting bridge is disabled. when running the application in OOB mode, and it still does nothing when running it in the browser!

Comment: Just looking over this error in a few places, this keeps coming up: do you have `<param name="enablehtmlaccess" value="true"/>` set on your Silverlight object in the mark-up?

Comment: I added that to the testpage that loads when I debug the project, but the image still doesn't load.